# Move large resized image in IE(7 and 8) is very slow

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, image, animation, performance

I'm writing some code to move dynamically an element on my page.

If i try to apply this at img element with generous dimension i notice in IE a very slow down effect.

Also, if the image is not displayed with its full size, IE seems to be more more slow.
I think IE apply a sort of resize algorithm for img every time it is refreshed...

There are some workaround for this?

Firefox and Opera are very very fast in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the image with a box (a DIV) when it starts moving, and replace the image when the move is complete.

JavaScript frameworks (like jQuery or [Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/)) often have optimized code for this type of activity and handle these problems internally for you.